# How to prove efficiency of a given estimator?

Tags: statistics, variance, parameter-estimation

So the question gave $D_1$ and $D_2$ as unbiased, efficient and consistent estimators of $\delta$ . $D_3$ is a new estimator which is obtained by taking a weighted average of $D_1$ and $D_2$ with one quarter of the weight placed on $D_1$. Now, the question is can I prove that $D_3$ is an efficient estimator of $\delta$?

I know for that for $D_3$ to be efficient, $\operatorname{Var} (D_3)$ has to be less than $\operatorname{Var} (D_1)$ and $\operatorname{Var} (D_3)$ has to be less than $\operatorname{Var} (D_2)$. I also know that

$$\operatorname{Var} (D_3) = \operatorname{Var} \left(\frac{1}{4D_1}+\frac{3}{4D_2}\right)$$

However, I'm not sure how to prove (or if it is even possible to prove) that $D_3$ is an efficient estimator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties of variance so that Var(D3)=(1/16)Var(D1)+(9/16)Var(D2). To prove the efficiency, you could perhaps use the Cramer-Rao bound and fisher information.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, my syllabus doesn't cover the Cramer-Rao bound or the fisher information. Would there be any other way to prove efficiency?

Comment: Consider: (1) Variances don't add in this way unless $D_1$ and $D_2$ are independent, which is not necessarily so. (2) If they are independent, then $D_3$ has a smaller variance than $D_1$ or $D_2$. (3) No need to prove $D_1$ and $D_2$ are efficient because that is assumed. (4) If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are both efficient, they must have the same variance.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! So would it be alright if I concluded that D3 is efficient if and only if D1 and D2 are independent? Thanks so much!